# how to use jquery to run highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea which gives the word count. On click of button I want that text to appear on the same html page that I can do with jquery text, but I also want to maintain the formatting as in the paragraphs etc.

I also want to highlight 4 words at a time and it should be running in ahead with 4 second time.

How can I do this with jQuery? Can anyone please help?

```
 $("form").submit(function() {

    $('#result').text($("textarea").val()).show();
        return true;

    });
```

Comment: Asking several questions in a single post is not good. You can ask as many questions as you want *in separate posts* though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well for showing same paragraph arrangement you'll have to replace all the new line characters with `<br/>` and then show it as text() of div. And Maybe you can use highlight: [JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for the other part of your requirement.

Well i've given you a general idea. Now don't expect me to write free code for you. :)